# couchdb/clouseau error in handshake: ou est clouseau?

Tags: scala, lucene, couchdb

On ubuntu 22.04 with couchdb 3.2.2, openJDK 8, I try to get lucene search to work by installing clouseau 2.21.2. I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/yenyih/how-to-setup-clouseau-for-couchdb-search-on-unix-like-systems-14gj). The service is available, but when I try to use it (as described in [this tutorial](https://dev.to/yenyih/query-in-apache-couchdb-clouseau-41ll)), the log indicates clouseau disconnects upon handshake with the following:

```
INFO scalang.node.ErlangHandler - channel disconnected org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext@7495b1fb [id: 0x5e0a511c, /127.0.0.1:40416 :> /127.0.0.1:40743] DISCONNECTED. peer: null
ERROR scalalang.node.ServerHandshakeHandler - Channel closed during handshake
```

while couchdb asks "ou est clouseau?"

Seems like I am almost there. Am I?

I tried veryfying that I really have OpenJDK 8 and not a newer version. I tried installing scala utils. I tried turning it off and on again.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working! (CouchDB - v3.3.2 and Clouseau - v2.21.6)

What I have done to fix this

Clouseau folder

Remove file: slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar

Add files: slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar, slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar (Download from https://download.jar-download.com/cache_jars/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.7/jar_files.zip)

change in file clouseau.ini

cookie=monster
(change `monster` to we can get cookie value from `\etc\vm.args` setcookie's value)